# Why are some tools on Tools toolbar not working in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, tools, toolbar, data-frame

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop, i've managed my map in the layout view, everything done, i was fine with the outcome, exported into a pdf file, then switched back to data view.

Now i am completely unable to use some of my tools from the "Tools" toolbar on this mxd.

If i open another mxd or add a new dataframe on those, everything works just fine, but on this one i am unable to zoom in/out or move it, however i am able to select features.

Also reference scale changed for (seemengly) no reason. I guess somehow i fixed even the dataframe view, not just the layout.

What happened? How can i move my map in data view again? Will the solution have effects in the layout?

Answer (score 1):

I've got my own answer:

I fixed it when i set in the layout view to fixed extents.

It can be undone at data frame properties.> data frame-> extent : automatic. BUT it completely moves the map in the layout view also, so its not exactly what i want, but i guess that's just how it works.

Comment: Have you tried repairing your. Mxd?